# Can anyone explain a little bit about the code below?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, flow-typed

So I am currently reviewing React-Redux code written with JS and Flow-Type. I have little experience in Flow-Type so the code below is a little bit confusing me.

First I have some actions for redux part.

```
export type allActions = 
|{|
   +type: "FIRST_ACTION_TYPE",
   +formType: FormType,
   +offset: number,
   +size: number
 |}
|{|
   +type: "SECOND_ACTION_TYPE",
|};
```

So my first question is what does |{||}| this expression mean?

And also the second question is for the `FormType` part. So above the actions there is the definition of `FormType`. Which is shown below

```
type FormProps = {
   prop_1?: string,
   prop_2?: number,
   prop_3: number
};

type FormType = RecordOf<FormProps>;
```

Can anyone please explain what this code above is doing?

Comment: Where are you seeing the `|{|`? In your editor?

Comment: It's in the code under a .js file with all the actions, action creators, and reducers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `allActions` is a union type that use to type Redux Dispatch. This allows flow to throw an error if you dispatch an invalid action.

```
|{|
   +type: "FIRST_ACTION_TYPE",
   +formType: FormType,
   +offset: number,
   +size: number
 |}
|{|
   +type: "SECOND_ACTION_TYPE",
|};
```

The first `|` is a bit confusing but is just an optional character that is commonly added by lints on multiline unions. It could be removed and not cause an error.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/

{|...|} define an exact object that cannot contain any additional properties. The `|` between them defines the union.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types

The `+` sign before marks each property as read only.

The `?` sign after each property in the form data marks each as optional.

The `recordOf` is generic type. I think it may be custom or perhaps an older version of flow.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-parameterized-generics

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense now. Would it be more clear to me if I read more about flow-type? The whole project is written in flow-type and sometimes I am very confused like this case

Comment: Absolutely, it's a bit of a learning curve but once it clicks you'll never want to use React with out it. It's also very close to typescript so you'll more comfortable when you come across that as well. https://flow.org/en/docs/react/

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!